# What to use in the blank space in order to add the "x" variable from class A without creating another object of A?

Tags: c#, inheritance, this

I have to use the `this` keyword in order to add all the 3 values of `x` present in the 3 classes.

I am not allowed to create an instance of class `A` in method `M1`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
        int op = c.M1();
        Console.WriteLine(c.x);
        Console.WriteLine();     
    }
}
public class A
{
    public int x = 10;
}
public class B:A
{
    public int x = 100;

}
public class C:B
{
    public int x = 1000;
    public int M1()
    {
        return (x + base.x + _____ ); 
        //What to use in the blank space in order to 
        //add the "x" variable from class A without 
        //creating another object of A
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Read some basic tutorials of "Ineritance" by googling.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your current instance (`this`) to `A`. You can use

`((A)this).x`

Heres the complete code of your method, how I would define it

```
public int M1()
{
    return (x + ((B)this).x + ((A)this).x ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public int M1()
{
    return (x+base.x+((A)this).x);
}
```

but if you take a look at constructor of your class C in decompiler

```
// method line 3
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
       instance default void '.ctor' ()  cil managed 
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x210c
  // Code size 18 (0x12)
  .maxstack 8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0 
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4 1000
  IL_0006:  stfld int32 stringy.C::x
  IL_000b:  ldarg.0 
  IL_000c:  call instance void class stringy.B::'.ctor'()
  IL_0011:  ret 
} // end of method C::.ctor
```

you will see that constructor of C will call constructor of B and similarly constructor of B will call constructor of A, so instance of base does exist and there is no need to create another object instance. To demonstrate that even more clearly here is how method M1 looks in IL

```
// method line 4
.method public hidebysig 
       instance default int32 M1 ()  cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2120
  // Code size 21 (0x15)
  .maxstack 8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0 
  IL_0001:  ldfld int32 stringy.C::x
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0 
  IL_0007:  ldfld int32 stringy.B::x
  IL_000c:  add 
  IL_000d:  ldarg.0 
  IL_000e:  ldfld int32 stringy.A::x
  IL_0013:  add 
  IL_0014:  ret 
} // end of method C::M1
```

That `stringy` is namespace.
BTW you should declare subclass like this

```
public class B:A
{
  public new int x = 100;
}
```

if you want to hide field x in base class.